# edit pdf header when download from html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, datatables

I'm using DataTables in my web application to display tabular data, and I've implemented export functionality to allow users to export the data to various formats such as PDF, Excel, and CSV. I've noticed that when exporting data, the header includes additional unwanted data, as shown in this screenshot. This issue also affects the copy action.

Here's how I've set up DataTables and the export buttons:
[screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPLde.png)
and this is the [screenshot of pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRr3S.png)

```
<!-- Included DataTables and related libraries -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='excel-bootstrap-table-filter-bundle.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Other libraries included -->
<!-- ... -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='buttons.html5.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jszip.min.js') }}"></script>

<!-- DataTable HTML -->
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">#</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Component Name</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Count</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Action</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Date</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Time</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Group Number</th>
            <th class="filter" scope="col">Remarks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Data rows -->
        {% set i = namespace(value=1) %}
        {% for history in histories %}
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{ i.value }}</td>
            {% set i.value=i.value+1 %}
            <td>{{ history.componentName }}</td>
            <td>{{ history.Count }}</td>
            <td>{{ history.action }}</td>
            <td>{{ history.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ history.time }}</td>
            <td style="text-transform: uppercase">{{ history.groupNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ history.reason }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- DataTable initialization and export button setup -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            paging: false,
            ordering: false,
            searching: true,
            info: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons: ['pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5']
                }
            ]
        });

        // Additional DataTable configurations and filtering code
    });
</script>
```

My goal is to have clean exports without the extra data, as shown in this screenshot. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help!